# extract lines between the lines in sed or awk

Tags: bash, awk, sed, tags, extract

Hi I got segment of log and I need to extract 
parts between the tags  and tags must be included.

The log looks like this
`2016/10/28 13:22:17 INFO
2016/10/28 13:22:17 INFO`

`<Command
      tId="27810237892289-789766789"
      user="root">
    <ChangeTAG
          a_var="22341431413"
          b_var="837431243413"
          status="activated"></ChangeTAG>
</Command> application=ui_6789 state=5 state_current=na
2016/10/28 13:22:19 INFO 
2016/10/28 13:22:19 INFO`

 `<Command
      tId="27810567892289-701226789"
      user="root">
    <ChangeTAG
          a_var="87656651413"
          b_var="345751243413"
          status="activated"></ChangeTAG>
</Command> application=ui_3444 state=1 state_current=na
2016/10/28 13:22:29 INFO 
2016/10/28 13:22:29 INFO`

and output should be like:
`<Command
      tId="27810237892289-789766789"
      user="root">
    <ChangeTAG
          a_var="22341431413"
          b_var="837431243413"
          status="activated"></ChangeTAG>
</Command>`
`<Command
      tId="27810567892289-701226789"
      user="root">
    <ChangeTAG
          a_var="87656651413"
          b_var="345751243413"
          status="activated"></ChangeTAG>
</Command>`
any Idea how to chop it from log in sed awk or grep ?

Comment: Your file looks like an xml file, you should use a xml parser (try xidel) instead.

Answer (score 1):

With GNU sed:

```
sed -n '/<Command/,/<\/Command/p' file
```

Comment: this doesnt work for me since there is more commnads tags in the file

Answer (score 0):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ awk '/<Command/{p=1} /<\/Command/{printf "%s", $1; p=0} p' file

<Command
      tId="27810237892289-789766789"
      user="root">
    <ChangeTAG
          a_var="22341431413"
          b_var="837431243413"
          status="activated"></ChangeTAG>
</Command> <Command
      tId="27810567892289-701226789"
      user="root">
    <ChangeTAG
          a_var="87656651413"
          b_var="345751243413"
          status="activated"></ChangeTAG>
```

Comment: this seems to work but in need the <Command tag on the new line

Comment: well, that wasn't the output when I answered.  It's simpler that way.  Change `printf "%s", $1` to `print $1`.

Answer (score 0):

With GNU awk for multi-char RS, RT, and gensub():

```
$ awk -v RS='</Command>' 'RT{print gensub(/.*(<Command)/,"\\1",1) RT}' file
<Command
      tId="27810237892289-789766789"
      user="root">
    <ChangeTAG
          a_var="22341431413"
          b_var="837431243413"
          status="activated"></ChangeTAG>
</Command>
<Command
      tId="27810567892289-701226789"
      user="root">
    <ChangeTAG
          a_var="87656651413"
          b_var="345751243413"
          status="activated"></ChangeTAG>
</Command>
```